# Cmake vs Clion dont understand the difference

Tags: cmake, clion

I am working on a project on linux and I dont understand 
what really is cmake?
I have clion IDE do I explicitly need to learn about cmake?
Does Clion have cmake internally?
I am working on object detection with open detection.

Comment: This might be helpful as well: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/2016.3/quick-cmake-tutorial.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CMake is sort of a wrapper around older, more complex, and often more powerful make systems.  Make systems are a big topic, but in short, it is their job to notice files and do something about it (compile, link, deploy, etc)

CLion is a full GUI IDE which in turn uses CMake to do its dirty work of tracking files and what to do about them.  Its primary purpose is to wrap up your compilation (via cmake) as well as give you text editors suited to the task at hand.  Importantly, it also is a GUI front end for your debugging needs.